# POST http://127:8000/api/v1/exemp 500 error when sending data to an API route within a WEB page in Laravel using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch, laravel-8

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/cotacao", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content"));
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
};
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
  products: [
    {
      description: "product1",
      barcode: "123456",
      price: 10,
      note: "note1"
    },
    {
      description: "product2",
      barcode: "654321",
      price: 20,
      note: "note2"
    }
  ]
}));
```

> xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN",
> document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content"));
> return
> document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute("content")
> = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute') at :1:51

Comment: code only in the body isn't a question - please make it clear what you are asking - but the issue is that `querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')` is null - without seeing the HTML of the page, the only hint is, make sure that tag exists

Comment: The error message in the question title and the error message in the quote in the body are completely unrelated. The exception occurring before the Ajax request is made means that you can't get a 500 error because the request is never made.

Comment: … and the URL in the title is different to the one in the code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[**solution**]
add 'Cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,

```
Cors::class{
return $next($request)
             ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
             ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
             ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
}
```